# NSURL always nil using URLWithString

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, nsurl

I am receiving url of images from a API and these images i want to show on collection view.

Here is my code

```
NSString *str = [imgArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

frstUrl=[NSURL URLWithString:str]; // <-- (APP Crash here )

[imageView setImageWithURL:frstUrl
          placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
[imageView setImageWithURL:frstUrl];
```

Error message:

> [__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd769560

---

The `NSLog` of the `str` object returns:

> str=( ( "hello.com/projects/newapp/uploads/…;, "hello.com/projects/newapp/uploads/…;,

Comment: Can you please show your imgArray array content?

Comment: Check the class of str to make sure it's actually a string.

Comment: It appears that the call to `[imgArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];` is actually giving you another `NSArray`.

Comment: @GenieWanted `frstUrl` is never created - the app crashes in the process of creating it.

Comment: Check your str in NSLog(@"str :%@", str);

Comment: NSLog `[str objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];`

Comment: @ Natarajan i did  NSLog(@"str :%@", str);  its returning images url and number of url its returning are 10.

Comment: @user3382857 Does the NSLog of str really have two sets of parentheses? I would have expected the `NSLog` of `imgArray` to have two, but that `str` would have had one set. It makes a big difference. Each set of parentheses reflects another level of nesting of `NSArray`. Thus `("url1","url2",...)` is an array of strings, whereas `(("url1","url2",...))` is, itself, an array, whose first object is an array. And if you're seeing that for `str`, that means that `imgArray` had _three_ levels of nesting, which seems unlikely, but that's what you're effectively telling us.

Comment: @Rob yes str really have two sets of parentheses,problem solved +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is telling you that the object that you retrieved from `imgArray` was not a `NSString`, but rather was, itself, an `NSArray`. Examine what you retrieved (either `NSLog` it or examine it in the debugger) and you'll see that it's an array.

For example, if the associated object in `imgArray` was returning, itself, another array, then you'd have to grab the details from that. If for example, the first item in that array was the image URL string, then you'd do something like:

```
NSArray *imgDetailsArray = imgArray[indexPath.item];

// let's assume that the first item in that array was the URL string, so let's grab the first item

NSString *str = imgDetailsArray[0];

// now we can use that string

frstUrl=[NSURL URLWithString:str];

[imageView setImageWithURL:frstUrl
          placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
[imageView setImageWithURL:frstUrl];
```

Comment: i already check it with debugger both imgArray and NSSting returning same number of elements but problem is here                        frstUrl=[NSURL URLWithString:str]; // <-- (APP Crash here )

Comment: @user3382857 The issue is that your `imgArray` is not a simple array of strings. It appears to be an array of arrays. So `[NSURL URLWithString:str]` returns an array, not a string. You might want to `NSLog` the `imgArray` and edit your question to include the results. You say you logged `str` and "its returning images url and number of url its returning are 10." That's my point. That's not a simple string.

Comment: i got your point and i am receiving respons like   str=(                ( here my 10 url                                                       )) i cnt share my urls pardon

Comment: @user3382857: If it is being logged as `( ( oneArray, secondArray ... ) )`, with two sets of parentheses, then your array of URLs is contained inside another array, so as Rob said, `[imgArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]` is returning an array because that is what's in `imgArray`.